# TFS 2013 Custom dashboard widget

Tags: tfs, custom-controls, dashboard

I have been tasked with creating a custom planning view from TFS.

I have a reasonable amount of experience with the TFS Api but I want to try and avoid having to create and maintain a new application for this.

I have looked at SSRS for TFS but I am unable to access all of the data I need (tags etc.) so this is not an option (as it will invalidate support).

I would ideally like to create a "widget" to appear on one of the TFS dashboards but am not sure where to start. The widget would also need to allow access to the TFS api to gather the data it needs to generate.

Please can someone advise where I may look to start or an alternative approach.

Comment: What kind of data you would like to add to TFS dashboard? In TFS2013, there is an easier way for you to customize the dashboard via pinning the queries or reports to the homepage. Please check my reply for the details.

Comment: I need to display tags along with the "Feature" titles in a tabular view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at http://integrate.visualstudio.com where you can find documentation for the TFS API. The REST API works for TFS 2015 and above.

While you can extend the web interface with Extensions (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS), this feature is not yet available in TFS on-premises as of TFS 2015 Update 1.

You can check the [published feature timeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/news/release-archive-vso) for updates, but at this time extensions for TFS are marked as "TBD".

Comment: Looks like I may have to wait for a new update in that case.

Comment: I now have TFS 2015 update 1 running and am sure there must be some way to create my own widget to use but I can't find any guidance or documentation on this anywhere. I have noticed that the ALM community has created a number of custom widgets so I was hoping there might be something somwhere?

Comment: There is currently no way to extend this in TFS or VSTS. You will see features first on VSTS and you may want to get an account so that you can check them out. http://tfs.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with TFS2013 + Update2 or a higher version of TFS, it is allowed for Team Administrators to customize TFS dashboard via **pinning** items to the homepage without writing any code.

For example, if you would like to add a chart into the dashboard, you just need to go to the query’s Charts page and pin it to the home page. See the following image (quoted from this MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj920199%28v=vs.120%29.aspx))

[image]